# Call Javascript function on iFrame reload

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, scroll

So I have the following problem: I have a website in an iFrame. I want the parent site to scroll up to the top once you go to a new page inside the iFrame, which it does via this JavaScript:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    if ('parentIFrame' in window) { 
        window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But, on one page I have a two-part form. If you submit the first form, you get to the second one, but both parts are in the same PHP document, so you stay on the same page, but the iFrame is reloaded. I want the page to scroll to the top once you submit the first form, but the above JavaScript doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use AJAX and a scrollable DIV if the content is from the same origin

Answer (score 0):

use iframe onload event that will get triggered, once frame loads content,
onload="myFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

During the first form submissiom submit the page through Ajax call back method